# In Firebase auth, 'recently' authenticated means how long ago?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to perform sensitive operations line update email, password etc. I understand that the user has to be 'recently' authenticated to perform such operations. I want to determine whether the user is recently authenticated before allowing to perform such operations rather than detecting the user auth status from the resulting error message. (this is to provide better user experience)

I have been searching for a method such as `isRecentlyAuthenticated()` but I could not find one. But I found `lastSignInTime` inside `user` `metadata`. I can compare `lastSignInTime` with current time only if I know what does 'recently' authenticated exactly mean in Firebase.

Please clarify:

(1) Is a method `isRecentlyAuthenticated()` available for us to use out of the box

(2) If not 'recently' means how long (1 minute, 5 minutes, 1 hour, or anything else) ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Authentication requires that the user has recently provided their credentials when you try to perform certain sensitive operations. The time period for this recency requirement is not specified, it is enforced by the Firebase Authentication serves, and can change without notice.

The way you're supposed to handle this in your code is by catching the error when you try an operation, and then requesting the user to sign in again.

Answer (score 1):

The [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user) includes references to "recently signed in", such as:

> Some security-sensitive actions—such as deleting an account, setting a primary email address, and changing a password—require that the user has ***recently signed in***.

Firebase uses [**ID Tokens**](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/openid-connect/id-tokens/) when performing security-sensitive actions.

> Firebase ID tokens are short lived and last for an hour; the refresh token can be used to retrieve new ID tokens.

As [Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen) pointed out, rather than checking to see if the `ID Token` is expired, you should handle the error when attempting one of these operations.

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

user.delete().then(function() {
  // User deleted.
}).catch(function(error) {
  if (error.code === 'auth/requires-recent-login') {
    // Require user to sign in again.
  }
});
```